# What is the time complexity of the inmutable.js List().reverse() function?

Tags: javascript, time-complexity

So having something like:

```js
const transactionsInReverseOrder = transactions.reverse()
```

what is the time complexity of the operation? I assume it would be O(n). But I don't know if the function is optimized in a certain way. Or even if it is possible.

Comment: Yeah, no way around `O(n)`

Comment: But I mean it is possible to define a backwards iterator, right? without moving the elements.  https://medium.com/@chanakyabhardwaj/es6-reverse-iterable-for-an-array-5dae91c02904 couldn't that be the case?